# How to target urls with specific characters in a query string for htaccess redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

I have a site that was converted to ExpressionEngine from a different blog platform, and I'm getting a bunch of crawl errors from previously indexed urls that now lead to an error page because ExpressionEngine doesn't allow certain characters in urls.

The urls that are causing the errors follow one of three patterns:

```
http://www.example.com/general/404/?404%3Bhttp://old.example.com:80/old-blog/random/segments
```

or

```
http://www.example.com/blog/?404%3Bhttp://old.example.com:80/old-blog/random/segments
```

or

```
http://www.example.com/blog/Default.aspx?404;http://old.example.com:80/old-blog/random/segments
```

I was able to redirect the urls from the third example using this code:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/Default.aspx?/?$ http://www.example.com/general/404/? [L,R=301]
```

Is there a way I can intercept the other URLS with htaccess before they hit EE and redirect them to my 404 page: http:www.example.com/general/404/? I'm not sure how to target them specifically since there is nothing before the ? in the query string url segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^404(%3B|;) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/general/404/? [L,R=301]
```